# nginx proxy pass: trailing slash, vars don't work

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I can't wrap my head around how this is not the same:

1. does not work

```
    set $upstream_app myapp;
    set $upstream_port 1234;
    set $upstream_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port/;
```

2. does work

   `proxy_pass http://myapp:1234/;`

I suppose it must have to do with the trailing slash. Even when I add the trailing slash to the var, it does not work.
In fact, if I only replace one part of the uri it already breaks.

Anybody got an idea? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I have a resolver in place.
`resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;`

Comment: `proxy_pass` with and without variables in the value, behave differently. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Comment: @RichardSmith I can't seem to find how the `proxy_pass` with variables behave differently. Can you elaborate, please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230270/nginx-using-variable-in-proxy-pass-breaks-routing
This didnt help either

Comment: From the documentation: "When variables are used in proxy_pass ..., if URI is specified in the directive, it is passed to the server as is, replacing the original request URI."